# How to check if user press <enter> ten times and reach the char size (100 chars) in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How can we check if the user press ten times the  and reach the char size limit?

if user press more than ten times the  key it display an alert, or if user typed more than one hundred chars it show another alert.

Take a look at my start [sample at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afHm8/5/)

```
Editable: <div contenteditable="true"
        style="width:200px;border:3px solid red;min-height:22px;" id="tes></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to check the number of enter hits like this:

```
$(function() {

    var enterCounter = 0;
    var charCounter = 0;

    $(".myDiv").keypress(function(event) {

        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            enterCounter += 1;
        };

        if(event.keyCode == 13 && enterCounter >= 10) {
            event.preventDefault();
        };

        if(enterCounter == 10) {
            alert("Too much of an enter");
        };
    });
});
```

And the same goes for number of characters, you just have to specify numeric interval representing the characters.

Or simplier way for character count is to get length of string each time you enter a character.

```
$(function() {
    $(".myDiv").keypress(function(event) {
        var text = $(".myDiv").text();
        if(text.length == 100) {
            alert("Too much characters");
            $(".myDiv").text($(this).text().substr(0, 100));
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: But how to check number of character ..?

Comment: you anser is work but I am facing one proble when some pne enter 10 enter it show alert .But user again press enter my div size again increase

Comment: can we prevent or stop increase the if user enter more than 10 enter

Comment: same case with user get the the alert more than 100  character but user able to write text in div

Comment: can we stop user when more than 100 character write and stop increasing the size of div when user enter 10 eneter

Comment: you can stop user being able to change the contents of the div as well as the size by adding this line of code into "if" condition: $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable').blur();

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava, if you remove this property how can you edit the text typed?

Comment: ok instead of this line of code you can add something like this to your character "if condition" which will stop you at 100 charactes, yet still allows you to edit the content $(".myDiv").text($(this).text().substr(0, 100));

Comment: You can check the code now. It sould work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the events and to stop the typing after the limits are reached.

To limit and to stop typing when both events occurs, the limit of  and the char size of your text box.

You must watch how this two parameters increase and when it reach the limit you need to call `event.preventDefault();` to stop typing.

```
<div class="prompt" contentEditable=true> </div> 
<script>
    var counter = 0, tamanho=100;
    var boxText;

    $('.prompt').keypress(function(event){
        boxText = $('.prompt').text();
        if(boxText.length>tamanho)  {    
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("reach the size of char");
        }

        if ( event.which == 13 ) {
            counter++;
            if (counter>=10){
                 event.preventDefault();//stop the enter action on the div content
                 console.log("reach the limit of enters");
            }
        }
     });
</script>
```

You can see [here](http://jsbin.com/oBiBoBE/33/watch?html,css,js,output) a sample of manipulation of this events.